# Closing database connection on JFrame close

Tags: java, database, swing, jframe, connection

I am coming from the web world where DB connection opening is on app server start and closing on its close. Currently I need to create a Swing app with db connection. Most probably I will do this without connection pool, but it's a consideration for me and it's not related to my problem. I will use SQLite db.

I can open a connection in the main method where I am creating the main `JFrame` but where to close it? In my opinion the best will be if its closed in on frame close - but how?

How to close properly the DB connection exactly when the main window (the program) is closed?

Comment: Set the default close operation of the frame to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, then add a `WindowListener` and disconnect the DB in the methods it prompts you to implement. Search on each & make an attempt.

Comment: Here is the link, which can explain you, how to write [Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        super.windowClosing(e);
        // Do your disconnect from the DB here.
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `super.windowClosing(e)` accomplish in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Make title bar read only so user can not close the JFrame by click to upper right cross button. Take a JButton to close JFrame. In actionPerformed method on click of button close the DB connection and write System.exit() method to exit from the application properly.

Comment: This isn't very good approach. User expects the title bar to work in certain way and it will confuse him. `WindowListener` approach is much better.